# What is the rationale for "structure with flexible array member shall not be a member of a structure"?

Tags: c, struct, language-lawyer, flexible-array-member

C11, 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers, Constraints, 3 (emphasis added):

> A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or function type (hence,
> a structure shall not contain an instance of itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance
> of itself), except that the last member of a structure with more than one named member
> may have incomplete array type; such a structure (and any union containing, possibly
> recursively, a member that is such a structure) **shall not be a member of a structure** or an
> element of an array.

Rationale for C, Revision 5.10, April-2003 (emphasis added):

> Similarly, structures containing flexible arrays **can’t occur in other structures** or in arrays.

So, Rationale for C doesn't provide a rationale. What is the rationale?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A structure with a flexible array member can only really be used properly if allocated dynamically.  For example:

```
struct s1 {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c[];
};
...
struct s1 *x = malloc(sizeof(struct s1) + 5 * sizeof(int));
```

Let's assume typical struct padding and `sizeof(int)==4`.  That would make `sizeof(struct s1)==8`.

Now imagine if such a struct was a member of another struct:

```
struct s2 {
    int a;
    struct s1 b;
    int c;
};
```

The `b` member of `struct s2` would start at offset 4.  But what about the `c` member?  Given that `sizeof(struct s1)==8`, that would make member `c` have offset 12.  But then there's no way for the `b` member to have any space set aside for its containing `c` member.

Because the offset of a given struct member is set at compile time, there is no way to allocate space for the flexible array member `c` inside of `struct s1`.

In theory, if the struct with a flexible array member was the last member:

```
struct s2 {
    int a;
    int b;
    struct s1 c;
};
```

Then it *could* work, but then then means that `struct s2` is also subject to the same rules as a struct with a flexible array member, causing a cascading effect.  This would make it more difficult to determine which structures are subject to this rule.

So a struct with a flexible array member is not allowed as a member of another struct or an array.

Comment: This does not explain why the rule for structures with flexible array members would not simply be the same as the rule for flexible array members: They must be last.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Can you elaborate? Which rule exactly?

Comment: @pmor: Your question asks about the rule that a structure with a flexible array member “shall not be a member of a structure.” That rule could be “shall not be a member of a structure other than the last member.” This answer does not give any reason against that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Indeed! Logically it can be the last member. (The similar case is "There is only one name space for tags even though three are possible". Then why not making three? Rationale doesn't answer that.)